# hacer focus en un input y colorear varios elementos

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy haciendo un "login", con usuario y contraseña y quisiera saber como hacer para que cuando hago focus en un input, me cambie el background de dos elementos. Lo he intentado así pero no me funciona.

```
.campos_login > div input:focus, .campos > div input, campos > div li {
     background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es que cuando el input este en modo focus, quisiera que el fondo del input se cambie y la etiqueta li tambien (es decir el fondo del icono), mas o menos sería esta idea.
[image]

La imagen es el modelo que estoy haciendo, pero no es mi login.

Mi problema es que no sé que selector poner.

```css
 .fondo_login{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  display: none;
 }
 *{
  margin:0;
 }
 .login{
     border: 0.5px solid black;
     margin: 10% auto;
     position: relative;
     width: 30%;
     height: 70%;
     display: block;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background: rgba(128, 128, 128,0.7);
     box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0 15px 5px -10px rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
 }
 .login > p{
  text-align: center;
     margin: 2% 0%;
     font-size: 2vw;
     color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
     padding: 2%;
     text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }
 .login p i{
  position: absolute;
     margin: 0 0 0 30%;
     font-size: 2vw;
     color: #717171;
     filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
     top: 3.8%;
     cursor:pointer;
 }
 .login .linea_bottom{
     background-color: black;
     border-style: none;
     height: 0.5px;
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;
 }
 .campos_login > div li{
     color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     padding: 5%;
     font-size: 2vw;
     border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
     box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset, 0px 0.5px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     position: relative;
 }
 .campos_login > div input{
     font-size: 1.5vw;
     width: 80%;
     padding: 5.6%;
     border: none;
     background: transparent;
     box-shadow: -2px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset, 0px 0.5px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
     color: #e2e2e2;
 }
 .campos_login > div input:focus{
  outline-style: none;
 }
 .campos_login > div input[type="password"]{
  padding: 5.55%;
 }
 .campos_login{
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     margin: 10% auto;
 }
 .campos_login > div{
  position: relative;
     padding: 10% 0;
      display:inline-flex;
 }
 .campos_login > div input:hover + .campos_login > div li + .campos_login div input{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);

 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="login">
  <p>Login<i class="fas fa-times close_login"></i></p>
  <hr class="linea_bottom">
  <div class="campos_login">
   <div>
    <li class="fa fa-user"></li>
    <input type="text" name="">
   </div>
   <div>
    <li class="fas fa-key"></li>
    <input type="password" name="">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar un [selector adyacente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_adyacentes) (`+`) para escoger a los elementos que sean *hermanos* del `input`. Algo así:

```
div > input:focus + li {
  background-color:#F00;
}
```

El problema de este selector es que solo busca los elementos hermanos que están después del primer selector (en este caso `div > input:focus`). Para hacerlo funcionar como quieres, es necesario modificar el HTML, para poner el `li` después del `input` y ajustarlo después por CSS.

Algo así: https://jsfiddle.net/b2scp8zr/1/

Para el caso de la pregunta quedaría así:

```css
.fondo_login{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  display: none;
 }
 *{
  margin:0;
 }
 .login{
     border: 0.5px solid black;
     margin: 10% auto;
     position: relative;
     width: 30%;
     height: 70%;
     display: block;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background: rgba(128, 128, 128,0.7);
     box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0 15px 5px -10px rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
 }
 .login > p{
  text-align: center;
     margin: 2% 0%;
     font-size: 2vw;
     color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
     padding: 2%;
     text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }
 .login p i{
  position: absolute;
     margin: 0 0 0 30%;
     font-size: 2vw;
     color: #717171;
     filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
     top: 3.8%;
     cursor:pointer;
 }
 .login .linea_bottom{
     background-color: black;
     border-style: none;
     height: 0.5px;
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;
 }
 .campos_login > div li{
     color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     padding: 5%;
     font-size: 2vw;
     border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
     box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset, 0px 0.5px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     position: absolute;
      left: 0;
 }
 .campos_login > div input{
     font-size: 1.5vw;
     width: 80%;
     padding: 5.6%;
     border: none;
     background: transparent;
     box-shadow: -2px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset, 0px 0.5px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
     color: #e2e2e2;
 }
 .campos_login > div input:focus{
  outline-style: none;
 }
 .campos_login > div input[type="password"]{
  padding: 5.55%;
 }
 .campos_login{
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     margin: 10% auto;
 }
 .campos_login > div{
  position: relative;
     padding: 10% 0;
      display:inline-flex;
 }
 .campos_login > div input:hover + .campos_login > div li + .campos_login div input{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);

 }
  
   .campos_login > div input:focus + li, .campos_login > div input:focus {
  background-color: #F00;

 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="login">
  <p>Login<i class="fas fa-times close_login"></i></p>
  <hr class="linea_bottom">
  <div class="campos_login">
   <div>
    <input type="text" name="">
        <li class="fa fa-user"></li>
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="password" name="">
        <li class="fas fa-key"></li>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Esto solo es posible si cambias el orden de los elementos ya que en css los selectores pueden ser los hermanos siguientes o los hijos, no puedes devolverte a un nivel superior (padre) o a un hermano anterior por lo que la solución que te presento es cambiando el orden de `li` e `input` y para que el elemento `li` siga estando a la izquierda le agrego float left

```css
.form-input li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.form-input input:focus, .form-input input:focus + i  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="login">
    <p>Login<i class="fas fa-times close_login"></i></p>
    <hr class="linea_bottom">
    <div class="campos_login">
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" name="">
            <li class="fa fa-user"></li>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="password" name="">
            <li class="fas fa-key"></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para complementar la respuesta añadiría que si desea mantener el orden de los elementos (que el li se pinte antes que el input) puede jugar con **display: flex** y **order**. https://jsfiddle.net/fdbjvs92/